# Finitely many prime pairs n apart

Tags: nt.number-theory

Is there an even natural number $n$ for which it is known that there are only finitely many prime pairs that are $n$ apart?

Comment: If it were known, this would be an everyday example mentioned as a counterexample in surely every text on the conjectured infinitude of the distribution of prime pairs of fixed gap.

Comment: The formulation "are $n$ apart" might be uneasy for non-English speakers: I guess it means primes $p,p'$ such that $p'-p=\pm n$.

Answer (score 4):

[Polignac's conjecture](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polignac%27s_conjecture) says that there is no such $n$.